# Google Reseller Api access data to customers

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am new to Google Reseller API. Google Reseller API access data to customers from My Reseller Account without authorization.

Scenario: 
I am adding a license of 1 user which needs to show to customer as soon as it looks like standalone of Own Reseller.

Comment: objective is showing my live reseller api data to customer , But each time it need to take my live data to show to customers.

Comment: Check the [`Customers: get`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/get#try-it) method to see a customer account already in your reseller management, or to see the minimal account information for an existing customer that you do not manage. To [manage a customer account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_customers), first order a new or transferred customer account and then use the API's Subscription resource to create and manage this customer's payment plan and product SKUs.

Comment: You can also test it on [**Try it!**](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/get#try-it) to check the method on live data and see the response.

Comment: Get Method works for oauth 2.0 it will give data to reseller while synchronize his account , for customer login he wont have this data i want my reseller data need to show to my client.